# There is a better way to get types from geocoding google maps?

Tags: c#, google-maps

Using c# I need to get from google maps every address type and I'm using foreach and assign values. There is a better way than next code?:

```
string street_number;
                string route;
                string locality;
                string administrative_area_level_3;
                string administrative_area_level_2;
                string administrative_area_level_1;
                string country;

                foreach (var addressComp in result.results[0].address_components)
                {
                    var addr = addressComp;

                    if (addr.types[0] == "street_number")
                        street_number = addr.long_name;
                    else if (addr.types[0] == "route")
                        route = addr.long_name;
                    else if (addr.types[0] == "locality")
                        locality = addr.long_name;
                    else if (addr.types[0] == "administrative_area_level_3")
                        administrative_area_level_3 = addr.long_name;
                    else if (addr.types[0] == "administrative_area_level_2")
                        administrative_area_level_2 = addr.long_name;
                    else if (addr.types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1")
                        administrative_area_level_1 = addr.long_name;
                    else if (addr.types[0] == "country")
                        country = addr.long_name;
                }
```

Comment: Have  a `Dictionary<string,string>`, where the key could be address type, and value could be `long_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more readable code for me it would be something like this using Linq

```
List<TypeOfAddressComponent> addressComponents result.results[0].address_components);

Func<List<TypeOfAddressComponent>, String, String> getValueFromAddressComponent =
(addressComponents, typeName) => addressComponents.Single(a => a.types[0] == typeName)
.Select(a => a.long_name);

string streetNumber = getValueFromAddressComponent(addressComponents, "streetNumber");
string route = getValueFromAddressComponent(addressComponents, "route");
...
```

May be is less efficient, but for me is much readable and simple.

Comment: Thank you Marc Cals. pleas how can i use your code? I copy/paste in my code and does not recognize "TypeOfAddressComponent" It says I need a "using" ? I know is me, I dont know how to use Linq.

Comment: Instead of TypeOfAddressComponent you have to put the object type of address_component. If you are using visual studio just put your cursor on the object and you will see the type object. Another way to do it is not use the List and directly do "string streetNumber = result.results[0].address_components.Single(a => a.types[0] = "street_number").Select(a => a.long_name);" but is less readable

Comment: Thanks again! now it says I cant convert string to bool here "a.types[0] = "street_number""

Comment: Update my solution, I did a newbie error typing for comparing you have to use "=="   "a.types[0] == "street_number""

Answer (score 1):

Using a [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) statement instead:

```
switch(addr.types[0]) {
    case "street_number":
       street_number = addr.long_name;
       break;
    case "route":
       route = addr.long_name;
       break;
    case "locality":
       locality = addr.long_name;
       break;
    case "administrative_area_level_3":
       administrative_area_level_3 = addr.long_name;
       break;
    case "administrative_area_level_2":
       administrative_area_level_2 = addr.long_name;
       break;
    case "administrative_area_level_1":
       administrative_area_level_1 = addr.long_name;
       break;
    case "country":
       country = addr.long_name;
       break;
    default:
       // Error: addr.long_name does not match a case.
       break;
}
```

...or as @Habib mentioned using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, string> geo_data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var addressComp in result.results[0].address_components)
{
    geo_data[addr.types[0]] = addr.long_name;
}
```

By using the dictionary the code takes significantly less lines but also becomes less readable and perhaps more complex. Might save data from results that you won't use in the application, so I would use switch in your case.